# GHC doesn't perform 2-stage partial application inlining

Tags: haskell, optimization, inline, ghc

I have the function:

```
{-# INLINE f #-}
f x =
    \ y ->
        \z -> ...
```

It is defined so (see [GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-pragma) about the trick) because I need 2-stage application inlining, ex.

```
comp (f a) ...
...
comp pAppliedF b1 b2 ... =
    f'1 = pAppliedF b1 -- I need these 2 functions inlined
    f'2 = pAppliedF b2
```

However, I obtain `Core` like this:

```
fa = \ y z -> ...
...
-- `comp` is inlined
-- Even though there are happy partial applications:
let f'1 = fa smth1
    f'2 = fa smth2
in ...
```

How to outwit GHC here?

**UPDATE**
In real world (huh):

- [`f`](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/4efddadf2c824f3b7c2c824018678997601b4c60/yarr/Data/Yarr/Shape.hs#L189)
- [`comp`](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/4efddadf2c824f3b7c2c824018678997601b4c60/yarr/Data/Yarr/Convolution/Repr.hs#L165), 20 lines below: [`f'1`, `f'2`](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/4efddadf2c824f3b7c2c824018678997601b4c60/yarr/Data/Yarr/Convolution/Repr.hs#L178), actually zipped in `fixed-vector`
- [program](https://gist.github.com/leventov/4730311/raw/5d036ba4175760fe25bdbc957cbb317608367dd4/blur.hs) (`comp (f a)` there), [run](https://gist.github.com/leventov/4730311/raw/3ad410e06cfc017b30dfaaba3e43b2bf4fc0e529/run) (with `-fexpose-all-unfoldings`), [`Core`](https://gist.github.com/leventov/4730311/raw/ad859c098f899134e5f897f06e5cafcebc4a81ef/blur-core.hs) -- `$wa2` in the latter for `fa`

Comment: Can I see more of the code? It could be that `f` isn't inlinable because it's recursive or something. And what was the command line for compiling?

Comment: From what you've provided, I think ghc is doing exactly what you're telling it to.  The call to `f a` is inlined and replaced with the body of `f`, applied to `smth1` and `smth2`.  I think you mean you want that application inlined as well.  To do that, you may need to name `\y -> ...` and mark that function INLINE too.  But you'll need to provide more code to be sure.  It's also very likely that there will be no gain from doing so.

Comment: 2John L: I tried to give a name to the second (`\y -> ...`) function, even with dummy parameters, to mess GHC, no effect

Comment: Could you give a full compiling example and say what you would hope for it to compile into?

Comment: 2shachaf: wait a minute, please...

Comment: @leventov Use `@` to notify somebody, not `2`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: example in question update

Comment: You may need to crank up the unfolding threshold. And I assume you're using -O2 as well?

Comment: I think the pseudocode sample you've posted in the question has been simplified to triviality.  Can you please just post the actual function you're having trouble with (along with links to the full project)?

Comment: @JohnL of cause. To be honest, sometimes there are no problems _even without chaining lambdas_, see [the line](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/4efddadf2c824f3b7c2c824018678997601b4c60/tests/color-trans.hs#L52) -- here all is inlined perfectly as I want. It is even more puzzling so, why ilining isn't performed as expected.

Comment: @JohnL I don't want to post actual functions because then I have to explain a lot of things which go out of the question scope.

Comment: The problem is that inlining is essentially a whole program pass in GHC, so it is impossible to explain your behavior without being able to see the unfolded code from your example.

Comment: @DonStewart Do you mean `Core` repr for "unfolded code"? In [the dump](https://gist.github.com/leventov/4730311/raw/ad859c098f899134e5f897f06e5cafcebc4a81ef/blur-core.hs) `$wa2` can be inlined almost literally (it will expectedly lead to dramatic code bloat, it is exactly what I want), but GHC strangely don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add {-# INLINE f'1 #-} and f'2 in the where clause for those definitions.

Comment: `f'1` and `f'2` are zipped in `fixed-vector` actually